# GWT: Adding click handler to an infoWindow - using Google Maps V1

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt, infowindow

In my GWT project, I have a map which displays an info window upon a user clicking on one of the various markers I have plotted on the map.  Once I have the coordinates, mark_coords, this is how I add the infoWindow:

```
                        map.getInfoWindow().open(mark_coords,
                                new InfoWindowContent(name +  "<br />" + description));
```

I want to add an icon into the infoWindow that is clickable.  However, I can't seem to find any documentation for how to do this using Google Maps V1 without various libraries.

If anyone has any suggestions, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a XML file with an ImageView, and [setOnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) for the ImageView.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="+@id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then you can create an InfoWindowAdapter, and override the [getInfoContents](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter.html#getInfoContents(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker)) method.

```
  class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

      private final View myContentsView;

      MyInfoWindowAdapter() {
          myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);
      }

      @Override
      public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
         ImageView imageView = ((ImageView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.imageView))
         imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {

             }
          });

         return myContentsView;
      }

      @Override
      public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return null;
      }

 }
```

Finally you can do `map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MyInfoWindowAdapter());` to call your custom InfoWindow.

You can visit [this short tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/01/create-custom-info-contents-for-by.html) for more details.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help..but this is for a GWT project, not android unfortunately..

Comment: You might want to checkout [this sample demo](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/source/browse/releases/maps/1.1/samples/hellomaps/src/com/google/gwt/maps/sample/hellomaps/client/InfoWindowDemo.java) for GWT.